# Is it possible to mock System.Windows.Window using moq

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a `AsyncDelegateCommand` which takes the parameter of `Window`, I tried mocking the class but I end with an exception `The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.`

The DeletegateCommand:

```
private AsyncDelegateCommand<Window> okCommand;

public AsyncDelegateCommand<Window> OkCommand => this.okCommand ?? (this.okCommand = new AsyncDelegateCommand<Window>(this.OkAsync));
```

The Method implementaion:

```
private async Task OkAsync(Window win)
{
   //Logic
}
```

The way I'm mocking it currently is using :

```
private Mock<Window> mockWindow;
this.mockWindow = new Mock<Window>();
await this.sut.OkCommand.ExecuteAsync(this.mockWindow.Object);
```

While debugging the object I can see the object value as an exception `this.mock Window.Object' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`

If it's not possible is there an alternative on how to achieve this?

Comment: if you are using xUnit
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.StaFact

Comment: @AthulRaj I'm using nUnit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567075/how-to-run-nunit-test-in-sta-thread

Comment: also why do you need to mock a window ? i thought we mocked interfaces

Comment: @AthulRaj How can you verify the methods without mocking it? I'm not able to mock IWindowService Since it's internal. and I guess adding the attribute `[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]` over the method does work.

Comment: @AthulRaj mocking `interface`s is certainly common but any `virtual` or `abstract` members of a `class` can also be mocked. I do think mocking `Window` is dubious but not because it's a `class`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that you need to pass a UI control to a command - especially one performing an async operation. In MVVM, commands usually live in the ViewModel layer, and the whole purpose of MVVM is clean separation between business logic and the UI.

Comment: @Peregrine how would you suggest separate the Window parameter as the operation is happening in the popped up window

Comment: @ThePiatre The parameter for a command would usually be a data object, not a UI control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding an attribute as suggested in the comments `[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]` over my test method

Ex:

```
[Test]
[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
public async Task TestMethod()
{
    //Logic
}
```